# Text writing while object passing

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, augmented-reality

I'm trying to achieve this effect but instead of the pen and animal who write the text:

[image: Example of what i want to achieve.]

I'm trying to do this when an AR target is active. Consider that it has to be in 3d preferably. I've the animal object, and the text that I'd like to write/show. I'd made a script to write the text letter by letter using TextMesh Pro but now I'm needing a way to write the text letter by letter behind the animal object while he's moving forward with the best possible accuracy.

Any idea how to achieve this ?